# Creating tags from fields

Tags: forms, tags, fields

Is it possible to create tags from fields, where someone selecting a certain option tags them with that option. I.E. selecting the volunteer option tags the new contact as volunteer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules).  However, I'd argue that in most cases you'd rather use a Smart Group.

If you're committed to using CiviRules though:

- You'll need two rules.  One with a trigger of "Any contact is added" and one with "Any contact is changed".  If this only applies to individuals, you can substitute the appropriate triggers.
- The condition will be "Field Value Comparison".
- The action will be "Add tag to contact".

Note that you may want another rule to *remove* the tag if the field is changed and the condition no longer applies.